# laravel broadcast.php pusher option not working

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, broadcast, pusher

I am working on a realtime chatting application and I am using websocket with laravel

I am using library beyoundcode/laravel-websocket

I have change broadcast driver to pusher and have configured broadcaster.php to this

```
    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 6001),
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'http'),
                'encrypted' => true,
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],
```

When I run an event using

```
event(new App\Events\UserStatusEvent())
```

Instead of sending message to localhost which is 127.0.0.1 stated in pusher option it sends to pusher.com

I clear clear my cache and config not changes

```
class UserStatusEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('status-update');
    }
}
```

.env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=array
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

PUSHER_APP_ID=skldfjiklkd
PUSHER_APP_KEY=sdlkfewif
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=slkdfifwef
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

bootstrap.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';


import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER ?? 'mt1',
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ? import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST : `ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});
```

Comment: Can you please update your question and include the following values from your .env file ? `QUEUE_CONNECTION`, `BROADCAST_DRIVER`, and all other keys that start with `PUSHER_*` ?
Also please include the `resources/js/bootstrap.js` file in your question.

P.S. `laravel-websockets` by BeyondCode is no longer maintained, it's highly recommended that you refrain from using it. Instead, wait for a few days because Laravel Reverb is about to be released, so it's a better option for the current time.

Comment: @EyadBereh I have updated my question. Thanks for the update on Laravel Reverb. Can you notify me when it is launched

Comment: The `.env` file looks legit, but is that your full `bootstrap.js` file? I think it's missing more code from the `pusher-js` client. 
Regarding Laravel Reverb, Taylor Otwell said that it will be released along with Laravel 11 next Tuesday, that's 12th of March.
When it gets released, I'll comment on this question to remind you.

Comment: @EyadBereh There are other code in bootstrap.js for echo but it is commented out. I want to be able to send messages to the laravel sockets first before uncommenting and using the echo code on bootstrap.js. I will be waiting for the laravel reverb update.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. The commented code is the code that's meant to connect to your `127.0.0.1:6001` server. Are you using the `pusher` JS client directly instead of Laravel Echo ?

Comment: @EyadBereh I am getting this error Pusher error: auth_key should be a valid app key. If I put the right keys it sends the messages to pusher dashboard instead of laravel-sockets. How do I change it. I have updted my question with new bootstrap.js code

Comment: Alright, you need to go to your `.env` file and set the `PUSHER_HOST` variable to `127.0.0.1` , and the `PUSHER_PORT` to `6001`, and comment the `cluster` key in the `bootstrap.js` file.

Comment: This is necessary to make the pusher-js client connect to your websocket server instead of pusher's one.

Comment: @EyadBereh I am getting this error Pusher error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: api-.pusher.com because I removed PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER from env. push is not connecting to my websocket yet with the changes

Comment: Please remove the `PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER` as well from your `.env`, and make sure to set the `PUSHER_SCHEME` to `http`

Comment: @EyadBereh I am getting this error Pusher error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: api-.pusher.com

Comment: Okay, in this case, go to your bootstrap.js file, and explicitly set the `wsHost` option to be `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @EyadBereh I am getting this error  Pusher error: auth_key should be a valid app key. Do I need pusher valid key since I am using echo. I used a valid key and messages are sent to Pusher dashboard instead of laravel-socket dashboard.